# DateTime.FromOADate equivalent in swift

Tags: ios, vb.net, swift

Is there any equivalent method for DateTime.FromOADate in swift?

I am trying to convert this VB code to swift

```
If Format(System.DateTime.FromOADate(v12 / 24), "ss") >= 30 Then
v13 = Format(System.DateTime.FromOADate((v12 + (1 / 60)) / 24), "HH:mm")
Else
v13 = Format(System.DateTime.FromOADate(v12 / 24), "HH:mm")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `func timeIntervalSinceDate(_ anotherDate: NSDate) -> NSTimeInterval` it returns an NSTimeInterval (a double) that represents the difference in seconds between the 2 dates.
[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/timeIntervalSinceDate:).

```
let interval =date.timeIntervalSinceDate(pastDate)
```

Comment: thanks for fast replay, The problem I have the date in Double not in Date format

Comment: If you already have  doubles that represents seconds, just make the difference between them